# Carrying a child out of a pram (back pain)

Tags: back-pain, lower-back

Working with toddlers, my girlfriend has to lift them in and out of various kinds of prams. That has led to lower back problems for her since the common lifting advice do not apply for all prams. In the case of some strollers, she can lift the kid without bending forward. However, in other cases that does not work.

What is the proper lifting technique in lifting a toddler in or out of a pram? Or, would you guys rather recommend some back exercises for her to get rid of her back pain?

Comment: With all of the different styles of available prams, the only generic technique would be to make sure to lift with the legs first instead of bending at the waist.  Either way, I'd plan on doing some strength training and stretching to make sure the muscles in the back are supported and flexible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend some lifting exercises.Lifting would:

1. Strengthen the posterior chain (back, hamstrings, bascially the backside of the body).
2. Lifts (deadlifts and squats) teach you how to recruit the correct muscles (usually glutes) and handle off center loads.

Typical lifts to explore :Deadlifts, good-mornings, back squats, front squats, and hamstring curls. Careful when doing deadlifts concentrating on back position and with squats watch knee position.

Often back pain is also caused by flexibility issues that can usually be traced to tight hamstrings. Try yoga if you think could be a contributing factor. As mentioned below Abdominal is also important.

Good luck

Update: I would just like to caution women who had a C-section to be extra careful. Pregnancy and C-sections weakens the Abdominal muscles, therefore it is important **to take it easy** and slowly start increasing the strength of the abs. Pay special attention to the lower abs.

Comment: Good, but maybe add something about strengthing the core musculature as well?

Comment: Agreed. Also be aware if you had a C-section, I would consult a medical professional, experienced mother, or some relevant agent.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you obtain the books from Stuart McGill. He gives really good (in my opinion) advices regarding back pain mitigation and training.

He is one of the few that combines medical treatment with training advices. Usually, traditional doctors will tell you 'It hurts ? Stop doing it' which is not acceptable for someone who enjoys training/performance. Mc Gill successfully brought a top lifter from the dead back (he suffered a serious back injury and was told that his career was over) to top performance. This is related in his book *Gift of injury*.

You can also google "Mc Gill podcast back pain" and will already find good free ressources about back pain from Mc Gill.